# Play audio one by one

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a list of audio files. How to make them play one by one? Right now If I click button play, they are playing all together.

```
const audioList = [ 'audio1', 'audio2', 'audio3', 'audio4', 'audio5' ]

let button = document.querySelector('#btnPlay').addEventListener('click', e=>{
    audioList.forEach(element => {
        let audio1 = new Audio(element);
        audio1.play();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using the audio element's 'ended' event and change the audio's src after end of each song.

my html file:

```html
<audio src=""></audio>
<button></button>
```

my js file:

```js
const songs = [ 'audio1', 'audio2', 'audio3', 'audio4', 'audio5' ]
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
const button = document.querySelector('button'); 

let songIndex = 0;
audio.src = songs[songIndex]

audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  songIndex++;
  if(songIndex >= songs.length) return;
  audio.src = songs[songIndex]
  audio.play()
})

document.addEventListener('click', () => audio.play())
```

Codepen demo : https://codepen.io/PatrykBuniX/pen/GRgGGyr
 I hope it helped you! :D

Comment: Hi @PatrykBuniX, thanks for your reply, but I'm getting Error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` here `audio.src = audioList[songIndex]`

Comment: I added real links in array above, you can just copy and past them in the code you posted. I also added `let button = document.querySelector('#btnPlay')` just right after the array.

Comment: They are playing all together because you are using forEach loop which is synchronous and won’t wait for song’s end. Try to use my code and paste your songs to the array.

Comment: I've updated my answer which works with your songs.